# Cannot insert playlistItem into playlist at specific position

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to insert a youtube video into my playlist at a specific position. According to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert#request-body), I should be able to by setting the `position` attribute. However, this settings seems to do nothing. Using the following code snippet, no errors are thrown and the video is inserted. The only problem is that it is inserted at the top of the playlist. The `position` attribute is ignored.

```
await google.youtube('v3').playlistItems.insert({
  auth,
  part: 'snippet',
  resource: {
    snippet: {
      playlistId,
      position: 69,
      resourceId: {
        kind: 'youtube#video',
        videoId: 'M7FIvfx5J10',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

I have tried putting `position` at different places in the object to no effect. I have also filed an issue on the official google api issue tracker but I did not get any response. I am using the official [`googleapis` node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis).

## Edit:

If I try to insert, then [update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/update), the update request throws `403 playlistItemsNotAccessible`. This has me thinking it might be a (poorly documented) permissions issue. My scopes is `[ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube' ]`.

## Edit 2:

The insert is using the `position` value. If I put `position: -12`, I get:
`Error: Invalid value for UnsignedInteger: -12`.

Comment: Try to use [`PlaylistItems: update`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/update) after you have inserted the video. If it's working then you can do it as workaround for now.

Comment: Thanks for the comment MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0. If I try to update, I get `403 playlistItemsNotAccessible`.

Comment: [`playlistItemsNotAccessible`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors) simply means that the request is not properly authorized to update the specified playlist item. You can refer to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) for the process of authorization.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 Do you know how I would go about authorizing this type of action? I tried with the scopes `[ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload' ]` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try testing it here [Apis explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.insert?part=snippet&_h=1&resource=%257B%250A++%2522snippet%2522%253A+%250A++%257B%250A++++%2522playlistId%2522%253A+%2522%2522%252C%250A++++%2522resourceId%2522%253A+%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522kind%2522%253A+%2522youtube%2523video%2522%252C%250A++++++%2522videoId%2522%253A+%2522M7FIvfx5J10%2522%250A++++%257D%252C%250A++++%2522position%2522%253A+%2522%2522%250A++%257D%250A%257D&) it will build the request body for you and you can use that in your code

```
{
 "snippet": {
  "playlistId": "",
  "resourceId": {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10"
  },
  "position": 69
 }
}
```

the full [request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource) body would be something like this

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": datetime,
    "channelId": string,
    "title": string,
    "description": string,
    "thumbnails": {
      (key): {
        "url": string,
        "width": unsigned integer,
        "height": unsigned integer
      }
    },
    "channelTitle": string,
    "playlistId": string,
    "position": unsigned integer,
    "resourceId": {
      "kind": string,
      "videoId": string,
    }
  },
  "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": string,
    "startAt": string,
    "endAt": string,
    "note": string,
    "videoPublishedAt": datetime
  },
  "status": {
    "privacyStatus": string
  }
}
```

## Update error

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.playlistItem",
    "reason": "playlistItemsNotAccessible",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

Remember that Youtube api is channel based if you are trying to access a different channel than the one that you authenticated to your going to see this error. The user whos playlist you are trying to add to must have authenticate your application and select the playlist on that channel. You cant update someone else's playlist without there permission.

Comment: I own the playlist and I am authenticating using my own account.

Comment: have you selected the correct channel when authenticated?

Comment: @DalmTo yes I did